# Does any Android app in Play console appear in Google Api Console

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-api-console

i have an app that uses game services. i was told to check something in the Google Api Console , but i can't see my project in the projects list at the Google Api Console. So , should my app appear there or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your App uses Game Services it should appear there. This would have been [created automatically by the Play Console when you added services to your game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling).